# Value Error when trying to match index in two lists

Tags: python, list, indexing

I am trying to code some simple flashcards in Python ( still learning!).

I can read in a text file, split into two lists ( keywords and definitions), find a random keyword (`chosenKeyword`) and return both the keyword and its index value from the keyword list BUT when I try to use that index value (which will be exactly the same in the second list as I read them in at the same time line by line) to match to the definition list I keep getting a `ValueError` telling me that the item is not in the list (which it is when I manually check). The problem is in my `possibleAnswers` function but I cannot work out what it is- any help would be great.

```
# declare an empty list for answers
answers = []

if keyword.index(chosenKey) == define.index(chosenKey):
    answers.append()
else:
    pass


# find the matching definition for the keyword and add to the answer list

wrongAnswers = random.sample(define,2)
while define.index(chosenKey) != wrongAnswers:
    answers.append(wrongAnswers)
    print(answers)
```

Comment: Please post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're doing, but that `answers.append()` doesn't look good.

Comment: this part is strange also `while define.index(chosenKey) != wrongAnswers`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think You have some issues in displayed code

This is the first one:

```
if keywords.index(chosenKey) == definitions.index(chosenKey):
```

As I understand You want to add correct answer to your answer list.

I would do this as follows:

```
if chosenKey in keywords:
    answers.append(definitions[keywords.index(chosenKey)])
else:
    pass
```

second part seems like someone tries to get two random options one of which should be correct answer

```
wrongAnswers = random.sample(define,2)
while definitions[keywords.index(chosenKey)] not in wrongAnswers:        
    wrongAnswers = random.sample(define,2)
answers = wrongAnswers
print(answers)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, this solution worked best for me although I have still played around with to get it working as I want it to. I could not get the suggested if statement to work unless I changed it around. I found the Online Python Tutor really useful for actually seeing what was happening in my lists and variables- thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

`list.index()` returns the index of a given *value* in the list:

```
>>> ['spam', 'ham', 'eggs'].index('ham')
1
```

but raises a `ValueError` when the item is not found in the list:

```
>>> ['spam', 'ham', 'eggs'].index('monty')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: 'monty' is not in list
```

If you have indices instead, just use indexing on the list:

```
>>> ['spam', 'ham', 'eggs'][1]
'ham'
```

If you wanted to pair up elements of two lists, use the [`zip()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) instead:

```
for kw, definition in zip(keyword, define):
    if kw == definition:
        # the values match at the same index.
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I understand what the Value Error means and how it relates to the index. I could not work out why if I had an index value ( which I checked was an int)from list 1 I could not just get the actual value back from list2 for that index position. I have tried out your suggestion but kept getting errors related to the comma "if kw,definition in zip(keyword,define):" and could not get it to work.

Comment: @user2127168: ah, that's because there was a typo in there; I meant that to be a `for` loop. My apologies.